# Pygame Rect Collision

Tags: python, class, pygame, overlapping

I am creating a game of Pong in Pygame with Python (obviously) and am new to Pygame so would like some help working the physics of when the ball touches the paddle, it will reverse speeds and go the opposite direction. Everything works so far, but when the ball goes to the paddle, it goes right through it and does not change direction. I have it worked out so the paddles do not leave the screen and the ball changes direction when it meets a wall, but not when the ball meets a paddle. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

My paddle class:

```
class Paddle:    
    def __init__(self, x, y):    
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = 40
        self.width = 10

    def draw(self, canvas):
         pygame.draw.rect(canvas, pygame.Color(0,0,255),(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
    def contains(self, ptX, ptY):
        return self.x < ptX < self.x + self.width & self.y < ptY < self.y + self.height
    def overlaps(self, otherRectangle):
        return otherRectangle.colliderect(Rect(self.x,self.y,self.height, self.width))
```

My ball class

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):    
        #position of ball
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        #speed of ball
        self.dx = 5
        self.dy = 5

        self.height = 10
        self.width = 10

    def draw(self, canvas):
        pygame.draw.rect(canvas, pygame.Color(0,255,0), (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 320
        self.y = 240

        self.dx = -self.dx
        self.dy = 5
```

My goal is to have the speed of the ball reverse (negative speed) when it touches the paddle or bounces off (overlapping points).

Comment: can you post your main loop code?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1joSOmt1qN5kBVXUnRuDvO97wt7e2Em4VgI-pXEsCTWg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Protip: Github Gists (https://gist.github.com/) are much nicer than Google docs for sharing code.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have is probably a little excessive. Let's go with something a bit more simple. Within your `draw` functions (on both `Ball` & `Paddle`), go ahead and make the start of your lines look like this:

```
self.rect = pygame.draw.rect...
```

Then you can use the [colliderect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) function:

```
if ball.rect.colliderect(paddle1):
    # Reverse, reverse!
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'overlaps'

Comment: It's alright, I appreciate your help. I still received error message:AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

Comment: You get 'Paddle' has no attribute 'overlaps'?

Comment: When I put:                                                            if paddle1.overlaps(ball):
            ball.dy *= -1                                              I get:                                                                          AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

Comment: Updated my answer - let's go with a different tack.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Did you change the `pygame.draw.rect` line like I said?

Answer (score 0):

For the collision use the code below but change the variables

If paddle1.colliderect(paddle2) or paddle2.colliderect(paddle1):
That is the ball direction in the x-axis
ballDirectionX*=-1