# Python Pygame Call Function

Tags: python, function, pygame

How would I call this function to check if one rectangle (class) overlaps with another class (ball)?

```
def overlaps(self, otherRectangle):
    return otherRectangle.colliderect(Rect(self.x,self.y,self.height, self.width))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of whatever class that's defined in, e.g.

```
class Rectangle:
    # Other definitions required here
    def overlaps(self, otherRectangle):
        return otherRectangle.colliderect(Rect(self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))


r_1 = Rectangle()
r_2 = Rectangle()

print(r_1.overlaps(r_2))
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But can you help me call the function as stated with the code in this question I posted? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071399/pygame-rect-collision) Its the question I posted about collision detection. Thanks