# Jumping verification code not working using the y-axis (pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When verifying the states of the player (running, jumping, idling), the jumping overrides them because y-axis velocity (the code has vectors included) does not stop although not moving(I think).

Jumping verification code:

```
if self.vel.y != 0:
   self.jumping = True
else:
   self.jumping = False
```

Idling verification code:

```
if self.vel.x == 0 and self.vel.y == 0:
   self.jumping = False
   self.running = False
```

Running verification code:

```
keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pg.K_a] or keys[pg.K_d] and not self.jumping:
    self.running = True
 else:
    self.running = False
```

Is there any other way to verify if the the player is jumping?

When removing this code there are no more jumping animations but the idling is working, before removing the code the idling did not work at all but the running worked with or without the code. 
I already tried break pointing the important bits and they all get passed.

I am using this code to animate the player, the animation code works perfectly fine.

Here is all the code for the `Player` class and `Wall` class:

**sprites.py**

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
import os
vec = pg.math.Vector2


game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')
animation_folder = os.path.join(img_folder, 'animations')

class Sprite_sheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.sprite_sheet = pg.image.load(os.path.join(animation_folder, filename)).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image


def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)


def collide_with_walls(sprite, group, dir):
    if dir == 'x':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if hits[0].rect.centerx > sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            if hits[0].rect.centerx < sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            sprite.vel.x = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centerx = sprite.pos.x
    if dir == 'y':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if hits[0].rect.centery > sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            if hits[0].rect.centery < sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom + sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            sprite.vel.y = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centery = sprite.pos.y


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.load_images()
        self.image = self.standing_frames_r[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.hit_rect = PLAYER_HIT_RECT
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y)
        self.jumping = False
        self.running = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.idle_right = True
        self.idle_left = False
        self.falling_right = True
        self.falling_left = False

    def load_images(self):
        #idle right
        self.spritesheet_idle = Sprite_sheet('idle.png')
        self.standing_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(0, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(19, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(38, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(57, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(76, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(95, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(114, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(133, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(152, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(171, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(190, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(209, 0, 19, 34)]
        for frame in self.standing_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # idle left
        self.standing_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.standing_frames_r:
            self.standing_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # walk right
        self.spritesheet_walk = Sprite_sheet('walk.png')
        self.walk_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(0, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(21, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(42, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(63, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(84, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(105, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(126, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(147, 0, 21, 33)]
        for frame in self.walk_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # walk left
        self.walk_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.walk_frames_r:
            self.walk_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # falling right
        self.spritesheet_falling = Sprite_sheet('falling.png')
        self.falling_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_falling.get_image(0, 0, 20, 35),
                                 self.spritesheet_falling.get_image(20, 0, 20, 35)]
        for frame in self.falling_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # falling left
            self.falling_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.falling_frames_r:
            self.falling_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))

    def jump(self):
        self.hit_rect.y += 1
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False, collide_hit_rect)
        self.hit_rect.y -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -6

    def animate(self):
        # determining the direction
        if self.vel.x > 0:
            self.idle_right = True
            self.idle_left = False
            self.falling_right = True
            self.falling_left = False
        if self.vel.x < 0:
            self.idle_right = False
            self.idle_left = True
            self.falling_right = False
            self.falling_left = True

        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        # Testing for the states

        if self.vel.y != 0:
            self.jumping = True
            self.running = False
        elif keys[pg.K_a] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.running = True
            self.jumping = False
        elif self.vel.y == 0:
            self.jumping = False
        else:
            self.jumping = False
            self.running = False

        # Animating (changing the image)
        if self.jumping:
            if now - self.last_update > 150:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.falling_frames_r)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if self.falling_right:
                    self.image = self.falling_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                elif self.falling_left:
                    self.image = self.falling_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

        if not self.jumping and not self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 200:
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frames_r)
                if self.idle_left:
                    self.image = self.standing_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                elif self.idle_right:
                    self.image = self.standing_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

        if self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 100:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walk_frames_r)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                else:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump()
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
        self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
        self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center


class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I would utilize collision detection. If the player isn't colliding with the ground, then it is jumping.

Comment: If you are using `Rect`s in your code, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073109/8390068).

Comment: @Qwerty I tried that already... And it didn't work `pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.hit_rect, self.game.walls, false`, it just kept falling

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer it's not about the rect(I use them of course) it is that why does the self.vel.y not equal 0 when touching an object? It's wierd

Comment: @Eric there isn't really an mcve for this as I don't know how to format it(that is what I am asking), if you are thinking otherwise, I could do one if you tell me what you what the mcve to do.

Comment: @TudorPopescu `self.vel.y` is only going to equal 0 if you set it to be 0. There is no magical code that will make everything make physical sense in pygame. You must do that code yourself. Of course, if you used collision detection and the sprite is touching an object, then you can set the velocity to 0 and then you could tell that the sprite isn't jumping.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer I set to 0 when colliding with blocks on the y axis(you can check it out in the code below)

Comment: By any chance are you following the pygame for beginners platformer tutorial from kids can program?

Comment: @Qwerty I am but I am implementing it from more than just one of his tutorial (I am not exactly following along)

Comment: @TudorPopescu it's good that you are trying your own thing and not just sticking to the tutorial

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values when running the game? I cannot do this myself because the code you gave is incomplete (I can't run it because parts are missing). Also, are you aware that you can only move in one direction with the state system you have? I mean that you cannot jump and move left or right at the same time. The code seems alright but I might be able to see the error if I could run it. If you added in the rest of the code that runs the game and post it here, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @Qwerty I already did his tutorial s

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer I updated the github page to include everything :)

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer I tried what you said and it thinks it is jumping while idling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code to the point where it answers your question and fixes your problem. The jumping verification now works, which is what your problem is. But I think that there are other parts of the code which need fixing, but I will leave that to you.

**Changes I made to the code:**

- Got rid of all uses of `self.hit_rect`. I have no idea why you needed this and why it was being used. In all cases I just changed it to `self.rect`. As far as I know,  you really only need one `rect` here.
- I commented out some of the code in the `collide_with_walls` function. I also removed the lines of code to do with the `hit_rect`. I also made the function `return True` or `return False` whenever based on whether there are any sprites in `hits`. This was done to allow for the code later on in the `update` method to work.

  - The `self.vel.y` variable is now set based on whether the player is colliding with the walls. I commented out most of the code with acceleration to simplify things a little. I added some of it back but you I'll leave the rest to you.
  - In the `update` method the `hit_rect` is not being used anymore either.

Here is the fixed code:

**sprites.py**

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
import os
vec = pg.math.Vector2


game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')
animation_folder = os.path.join(img_folder, 'animations')

class Sprite_sheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.sprite_sheet = pg.image.load(os.path.join(animation_folder, filename)).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image


def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.rect.colliderect(two.rect)


def collide_with_walls(sprite, group, dir):
    if dir == 'x':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect )
        if hits:
            # if hits[0].rect.centerx > sprite.rect.centerx:
                # sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - sprite.rect.width / 2
            # if hits[0].rect.centerx < sprite.rect.centerx:
                # sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + sprite.rect.width / 2
            sprite.vel.x = 0
            return True

    if dir == 'y':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            # if hits[0].rect.centery > sprite.rect.centery:
                # sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - sprite.rect.height / 2
            # if hits[0].rect.centery < sprite.rect.centery:
                # sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom + sprite.rect.height / 2
            sprite.vel.y = 0    
            return True

    if hits == []:
        return False
    elif hits != []:
        return True 


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.load_images()
        self.image = self.standing_frames_r[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.rect.center = (x, y)


        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y)
        self.jumping = False
        self.running = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.idle_right = True
        self.idle_left = False
        self.falling_right = True
        self.falling_left = False

        # hit_rect

    def load_images(self):
        #idle right
        self.spritesheet_idle = Sprite_sheet('idle.png')
        self.standing_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(0, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(19, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(38, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(57, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(76, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(95, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(114, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(133, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(152, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(171, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(190, 0, 19, 34),
                                  self.spritesheet_idle.get_image(209, 0, 19, 34)]
        for frame in self.standing_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # idle left
        self.standing_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.standing_frames_r:
            self.standing_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # walk right
        self.spritesheet_walk = Sprite_sheet('walk.png')
        self.walk_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(0, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(21, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(42, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(63, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(84, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(105, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(126, 0, 21, 33),
                              self.spritesheet_walk.get_image(147, 0, 21, 33)]
        for frame in self.walk_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # walk left
        self.walk_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.walk_frames_r:
            self.walk_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # falling right
        self.spritesheet_falling = Sprite_sheet('falling.png')
        self.falling_frames_r = [self.spritesheet_falling.get_image(0, 0, 20, 35),
                                 self.spritesheet_falling.get_image(20, 0, 20, 35)]
        for frame in self.falling_frames_r:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # falling left
            self.falling_frames_l = []
        for frame in self.falling_frames_r:
            self.falling_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False, collide_hit_rect)
        self.rect.y -= 1
        if hits:
            print("Jump")
            self.vel.y = -30


    def animate(self):
        # determining the direction
        if self.vel.x > 0:
            self.idle_right = True
            self.idle_left = False
            self.falling_right = True
            self.falling_left = False
        if self.vel.x < 0:
            self.idle_right = False
            self.idle_left = True
            self.falling_right = False
            self.falling_left = True

        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        # Testing for the states

        if self.vel.y != 0:
            self.jumping = True
            self.running = False
        elif keys[pg.K_a] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.running = True
            self.jumping = False
        elif self.vel.y == 0:
            self.jumping = False
        else:
            self.jumping = False
            self.running = False

        print(self.jumping)

        # Animating (changing the image)
        if self.jumping:
            if now - self.last_update > 150:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.falling_frames_r)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if self.falling_right:
                    self.image = self.falling_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                elif self.falling_left:
                    self.image = self.falling_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

        if not self.jumping and not self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 200:
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frames_r)
                if self.idle_left:
                    self.image = self.standing_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                elif self.idle_right:
                    self.image = self.standing_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

        if self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 100:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walk_frames_r)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                else:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

    def update(self):
        self.animate()

        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION

        if collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'y'):
            # print("Colliding")
            self.vel.y = 0
            self.acc.y = 0
        else:
            # print("Falling")
            self.vel.y = 2

        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump()

        if self.vel.y > 0:
            self.vel.y += PLAYER_GRAV

        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        self.rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        self.rect.centery = self.pos.y


class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any more problems post a comment below!

Comment: @MichealO'Dweyer I did that so the rect doesn't change and as when changing between the images, it changes. So when hitting a wall and it changes the rect it will think it is the wall as the rect will be bigger and it glitch to another part of the map.

Comment: can you send me a link to the code, if you change the code to the original github, I won't mind.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow posted the answer before I was done writing. Give me another minute and I'll post the other changes and code.

Comment: @TudorPopescu I see the point of using `hit_rect` now. You should be able to add it back in easily enough. All I did to fix the problem was print out the values and make sure they were what I expected them to be. If not I just tweaked and changed the code to try get it to work. Make sure everything that you do makes sense and if the other values are getting affected by code that you added in, take it out and try fix it. Good Luck!

Comment: That is very useful! I tried it and it worked, but how did you actually make it to say it is not jumping, I'm trying to get my head around this but I don't see a clear way you made it to not think it jumping, thanks again!

Comment: Simple. I printed out `self.jumping` in the `update` method. I probably should have left that line in there but if you add it in you can see it for yourself :D

Comment: I mean how did you get to make `self.jumping` to equal false while on the floor?

Comment: Ah I see. When the `Player` is colliding with the ground, I set `self.vel.y = 0`. Then in `animate()`, the line `elif self.vel.y == 0:` will be `True` and then `self.jumping = False` is executed. Hope this explains it for you!

Comment: I tried doing that in my code but I don't know why, it just won't register it >:(. Can you please copy and paste the code I have to input. Sorry for disturbing you so many times.

Comment: Ask me anytime ;D Just use my version of `sprites.py` instead of yours. I commented out lines of code that were causing issues for me. You can try adding them back in but at the moment they don't work properly. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/michealodwyer26/1443bfc912d38e2875cea555c8c56d94) with the files but I only changed code in `sprites.py`. For now, just use the exact file I was using because the state system in that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I finally made my code work!

Comment: Glad I could help you! Good luck with the rest of your game ;D

Answer (score 1):

Can you consolidate your state checking code in one place to prevent race conditions?

```
if self.vel.y != 0:
    self.jumping = True
    self.running = False
elif keys[pg.K_a] or keys[pg.K_d]:
    # perhaps modify self.vel.x here?
    self.running = True
    self.jumping = False
else:  # must be idle here
    self.running = False
    self.jumping = False
```

Comment: Somehow it still doesn't work, maybe it's something with the animations? I will send you the section of the code when I am home(I tried it a bit at home but I had to go)

Comment: I think you should modify `self.vel` when you receive input and detect collision. Eric already suggested it in the comments of his code above. `self.vel` isn't going to be set to different values by itself unless you actually set it yourself.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer [Here is the link for this part of the code](https://github.com/Tudor0404/Stackoverflow-Help/tree/master/help%202)